# cassandraunit throws Dataset not found error

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, cassandra

I am using `cassandra-unit 3.0.0.1` from [here](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit) but it is throwing `dataset not found error`

```
@Rule
public CassandraCQLUnit cassProvider = new CassandraCQLUnit(new ClassPathCQLDataSet("simple.cql","keyspaceNameToCreate"));
```

is there any other plugins i need to use or is it a bug in cassandra-unit?

### EDITED

I have run my test in debug mode and found that the `getInputDataSetLocation` is returning `null` for me in `ClassPathCQLDataSet.java`

```
protected InputStream getInputDataSetLocation(String dataSetLocation) {  //dataSetLocation: "simple.sql"
    InputStream inputDataSetLocation = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + dataSetLocation);  // inputDataSetLocation: null
//when i run test for cassandraunit-example app i get BufferedInputStream@924 but I am getting null here which is causing error
    return inputDataSetLocation;
}
```

Please let me know if i am missing anything here. Thanks a ton

Comment: Are you sure that simple.cql is actually on the classpath?

Comment: yes it is in classpath and works with `@CassandraDataSet (value = { "simple.cql"})` but not like above